# Using the value of Javascript variable in django template to render template context

Tags: javascript, django

***Please do not mark this question as invalid. I didn't find any question in stackoverflow with the problem mentioned below.***

I have a django template. I pass the following context to it

```
context = {
'1_title': 'Title 1',
'2_title': 'Title 2',
'3_title': 'Title 3',
'4_title': 'Title 4',
}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I have a HTML file where I have a dropdown. The dropdown have values like 1,2,3,4. I have registered a onClick function to it.

I need to achieve this functionality. I will get the value in onClick function. Then I will concatenate the received value with _title and store to it a javascript variable. Now I need to use that javascript variable to reference django context. I am not able to achieve this. I have googled and did extensive searching in stackoverflow. None seem to answer my question.

The javascript function looks like this:

```
function getContextValue(value) {
var key = value + '_title'; 
return {{ key }}
}
```

If I select 1 in the dropdown, then the above function will have key as 1_title. I need to return the 1_title value from context which is Title 1.

For me it doesn't work and returns 1_title only. I have even tried return {{ 'key' }} . In this it returns key.

Stackoverflow community please be kind. This may be a simple question for you but not for me.

Comment: I added an generic answer how to expose template context data to JS. I'm not sure though if this is what you are asking for. Anyway I hope it points you in  the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you wann access the context infos in JS you need to deliver it to JS somehow.

Change your context to something like this for easier access in the template.

```
context = {}
context['data_for_select'] = {
'1_title': 'Title 1',
'2_title': 'Title 2',
'3_title': 'Title 3',
'4_title': 'Title 4',
}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I assume you have something like this in the template:

```
<select name="dropdown">
  {% for key, title in data_for_select.items %}
    <option value="{{key}}">{{title}}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>
```

You can now render the context data somewhere in the DOM for your JS method.
Django provides a handy template filter called **json_script** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script

```
{{ data_for_select|json_script:"select-data" }}
```

You can use it in JS like:

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('select-data').textContent);
```

This way you have exposed your template context data to JS.